# Problem with multiple jQuery slideshows

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle

Basically i'm setting up a page with mutiple slideshows using the jQuery Cycle plugin. Each slideshow('.slideshow') has it own navigation in the form of a pager('.controls'). However everytime i click a pager icon all the slideshows obn the page fade to the next slide. How can I prevent this so that only the slideshow in question has the transisiton.I thought my code below would work but it isn't, and how do i show which pager icon is selected?

My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slideshow').each(function(){
var $this = $(this), $ss = $this.closest('.slideshow');
var pager = $ss.find('.controls');

$this.cycle({
fx:     'fade',
speed:  'slow',
timeout: 5000,
pager:  pager,
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
// return sel string for existing anchor
return '.controls li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
}
}); 

});
});
```

the html looks like this but with multiples on the page:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slideshow">
<a href="#" class="slider-item"><img src="img/temp-featuredwork.png" alt="icon" width="545" height="254" border="0" /></a>
<a href="#" class="slider-item"><img src="img/temp-featuredwork.png" alt="icon" width="545" height="254" border="0" /></a>
 <a href="#" class="slider-item"><img src="img/temp-featuredwork.png" alt="icon" width="545" height="254" border="0" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="slider-item"><img src="img/temp-featuredwork.png" alt="icon" width="545" height="254" border="0" /></a>
</div>
    </div>
     <!--/slider-->
    <ul class="controls">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part seems odd:

```
$('.slideshow').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this), $ss = $this.closest('.slideshow');
  var pager = $ss.find('.controls');
```

Try

```
$('.slideshow').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
var pager = $this.find('.controls');
```

You've already got a reference to the .slideshow element thats matched in $this, so you don't need ss.

If this doesn't work, please post a snippet of your HTML, or even better, setup a test on http://jsfiddle.net and link it here.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, I got the $ss part from another question on the site. I've tried your code but it still doesn't work. All the slideshow still fade in on the same controls. I did notice though that only the top conrtols work, others don't